# I want to extract 3rd line from a text input

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have to extract the third line of a text.

```py
URL = 'https://simonsmith.github.io/github-user-search/#/search?q=benjamn'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(URL)
time.sleep(20)
content = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    n=link.get('href')
    n = re.sub(r"\#",'',n)
    print(n)
```

In this example I would only collect *benjamn* from the output and discard the rest.

OUTPUT:

```
/
https://developer.github.com/v3/
/benjamn
/BenjamNathan
/benjamni
/benjamnnzz
/BenjamnTal
/benjamncresnik
/benjamn1012990
/benjamnsmith
/benjamn77
/BENJAMNDO4FO
/benjamnzzzz
/benjamn25
/benjamnn
/benjamn2
/benjamnwilliams
https://github.com/simonsmith/github-user-search
```

Comment: Consider to use [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/), if English is not your native language.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
```

Suppose you instead had:

```
links = list(soup.find_all('a'))
for link in links:
```

Then `links[2]` would contain the desired link.

Equivalently, you could use:

```
for i, link in enumerate(soup.find_all('a')):
```

and focus on the particular link where `i == 2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead better refine your selector and use a css selector

if you use either

```
li .u-flex
```

or

```
[class^=User].u-flex
```

the first being faster; you will get only the 15 links for people. If you then use `find_element_by_css_selector`, you will only return the first match.

That is:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("li .u-flex").get_attribute("href")
```

No need for `BeautifulSoup` but the equivalent is:

```
soup.select_one('li .u-flex')['href']
```

Answer (score 1):

To fetch the value `benjamn` use `WebdriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable` with following xpath.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

URL = 'https://simonsmith.github.io/github-user-search/#/search?q=benjamn'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(URL)
element=WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//a[starts-with(@class,'User_')]//p[starts-with(@class,'User_')])[1]")))
print(element.text)
```

### Output Printed on console:

> benjamn

---

To Print all the text values use following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

URL = 'https://simonsmith.github.io/github-user-search/#/search?q=benjamn'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(URL)
elements=WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//a[starts-with(@class,'User_')]//p[starts-with(@class,'User_')]")))

for element in elements:
 print(element.text)
```

Output:

```
benjamn
BenjamNathan
benjamni
benjamnnzz
BenjamnTal
benjamncresnik
benjamn1012990
benjamnsmith
benjamn77
BENJAMNDO4FO
benjamnzzzz
benjamn25
benjamnn
benjamn2
benjamnwilliams
```

Answer (score 1):

You can grab that link using selenium making use of xpath and surely not hardcoding index like the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

LINK = 'https://simonsmith.github.io/github-user-search/#/search?q=benjamn'

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get(LINK)
    expected_link = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[./*[contains(@class,'username')]]")))
    print(expected_link.get_attribute("href"))
```

Output:

```
https://simonsmith.github.io/github-user-search/#/benjamn
```